# UIView progressive animation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewanimation

The standard `UIView` `animateWithDuration:` block works great for animations that have require a single animation effect, i.e. resize and/or move.

Is there a way to make the animation progressive, such that the animation starts slow, and gains speed as it progresses?

I could try nested `animateWithDuration:` blocks, placing subsequent blocks in the completion handler, but that way the animation is a little 'ragged'. I wish to make the animation smooth.

One idea that comes to mind is that I create a recursive function as follows:

```
- (void) animateToYOrigin:(CGFloat)yOrigin{

    if (myView.frame.origin.y < 1){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                         animations:^{

                        CGRect rect = myView.frame;
                        rect.origin.y = yOrigin;
                        myView.frame = rect;

                       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        [self animateToYOrigin:yOrigin /2];
          }];
    }
}
```

I am looking for a refined solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                      delay:delay
                    options:OPTION_HERE
                 animations:anims
                 completion:completion]
```

method and pass UIViewAnimationOptions where it says OPTION_HERE. You can use basic ease in/out options by default. If you need more options you can [check out this git repo](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTAnimation). In MTTimingFuncations.h/c you can find multiple options you can pass.